# C# HttpClient return Status WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

I have only one method for Api Request as follow

```
private async Task<Site> getSiteAsync(string siteId)
{
    Site site = null;
    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync( 
        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, httpClient.BaseAddress + $"api/sites/{siteId}"));
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        site = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Site>(stream, serializerOptions);
    }
    return site;
}
```

When I try to call it from my MainClass the first call (a) works fine, but the b,c and d they all return me the `Status` = `WaitingForActivation`.

```
private readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
private readonly JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();

public MainWindow()
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://localhost:5000/MyApi/");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    serializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;

    var a = getSiteAsync("0001"); << I only get the value of this call.
    var b = getSiteAsync("0002");
    var c = getSiteAsync("0003");
    var d = getSiteAsync("0004");
    InitializeComponent(); 
}
```

How can I get the Result of b,c and d ?

Comment: You should await the calls.

Comment: @mm8 How ? , I cannot make my Constructor(MainWindow) to be the async method. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You could for example handle the `Loaded` event. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should await the calls and since you can only do this in an `async` method and not in a constructor, you should move your code to a method or an event handler:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://localhost:5000/MyApi/");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    serializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;

    Loaded += async (s, e) =>
    {
        var a = await getSiteAsync("0001");
        var b = await getSiteAsync("0002");
        var c = await getSiteAsync("0003");
        var d = await getSiteAsync("0004");
    };

    InitializeComponent();
}
```